# Products on sale quantity

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, entity-framework

### The goal

Count products on sale, regardless of the category.

### A little description

There is a table in my database called `Categories`. Follow the structure:

```
'Category_Id', 'tinyint(3)'
'Category_Name', 'varchar(45)'
'Category_Products_Quantity', 'int(11)'
```

All of the products of my application have a category and I set this at `Products` table — referencing category's id.

As you can see, there is — in my table — a column called `Category_Products_Quantity`. This column stores the number of products in some category. To increase or decrease the products quantity, I have two triggers: one to incrase; one to decrease.

So far, so good, huh?

### The problem

The problem appears when I need to count the quantity of products on sale. I have a third table called `Market_Products` which stores the products in their respective markets. Follow the structure:

```
'Product_Id', 'int(11)'
'Market_Id', 'int(11)'
'Product_Price', 'decimal(10,2)'
'Product_State', 'int(11)'
```

Can you see `Product_State`? So, this column is responsible to flag if the product is on sale or not. "Sale" is not a category, unlike "Bazaar" which is a category.

My question is: **In this scenario, how can I count the products whose `Product_State` is nonzero?**

### Technical details

I'm working with C#.Net 4.0 + MVC 4 + Razor Engine 2 + Entity Framework 5 + MySQL.

### Shortly

I have an online store application. Entity Framework generated the CRUD for me. My application have products and categories. I can count how many products are in each category. The price of each product is determined by the different markets. These markets can mark an item as an offer. **I need to treat an offer as a category to count how many products are offers.**

Comment: what does your current SQL query look like? This is an extremely basic SQL question

Comment: @MattBusche I'm using Entity Framework and I do not know which was the query generated by him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you what you're looking for.

```
SELECT COUNT(Product_ID) 
FROM Markets_Products
WHERE Product_ID <> 0
```

If `NULL` is possible in your `Product_ID` column then you'll want to change your `WHERE` clause to this

```
WHERE isNull(Product_ID,'') <> 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    SELECT COUNT(Product_ID) 
    FROM Markets_Products
    WHERE Product_ID IS NOT NULL
```

I hope it helps